# How to get all the Queues in one node

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I want fetch the all the available Queues in the one machine using Java API(Spring-AMQP). I didn't find the right API. Can anyone suggest the API for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [REST API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html) for that; the AMQP protocol itself has no support for it.

Spring AMQP 1.5 (currently milestone 1) has a [wrapper for the java REST client - RabbitManagementTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/html/_reference.html#management-template) or you can use the java client [provided by the rabbitmq](https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop) team directly.

Comment: I tried with 1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version but couldn't able to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.http.client.Client exception. Can you please tell me dependency jars to resolve it.

Used below jars - 
1> spring-amqp:1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' 
2> spring-rabbit:1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: See the README at [the link for the rabbit http client I provided](https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop) for version and repo information. Spring AMQP uses that library too.

Answer (score 0):

Below HTTP get call will list you all queue

http://localhost:55672/api/queues

List all queues under a particular vhost:
http://localhost:55672/api/queues/vhost_name

Refer the [doc](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) for more details.